# Setting up a login page for wireless hotspot

Tags: networking, windows-7, wireless

I want set up wireless access point (hotspot) on a notebook running Windows 7. There is a few applications available for setting WiFi hotspot, e.g. Connectify, Virtual Access Point (Virtual AP), MyPublicWiFi, etc.
I want protect access to this hotspot with login page, so when user click on WiFi SSID name, it should be redirected to the hotspot login page associated with this SSID, with login form. User should provide valid username and password to access network. What is the most simple way to set up login page? Additionally, the user input data should be stored in log file to verify credentials and some statistic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the hotspot software creator from antamedia

you may download a free version here

http://www.antamedia.com/download/hotspot-installer-v3.exe

here below is manual the assists you how to set the hotspot site

http://www.antamedia.com/download/hotspot-manual.pdf

enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for tips. This software require to have two network cards installed on PC. I would like an approach that use virtualisation of a few virtual wireless adapters based on a single physical WLAN adapter.